# Cleartext http traffic not permitted

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm working in one project and I'm stuck in the implementation of login/signup page. When I try to implement the code it gives me the error `Cleartext HTTP traffic to 192.168.1.130 not permitted`. I checked the `ipconfig` and that was my IPv4 so I have added `192.168.1.130`, but I have also checked `127.0.0.1`, but that one doesn't work either.

I have tried implementing `<domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.130</domain>` however that one doesn't work(implementation of `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` doesn't work either).

I'm using XAMPP for the back-end and if I run php code everything works good, so no problem with that. Problem is in the Android Studio(I'm using Kotlin).

For the Emulator I'm using Genymotion emulator(it uses VirtualBox).

Here's the code for the button that takes the `url`. I have checked everything, but still nothing achieved.

```
login.setOnClickListener {
            var url = "http://192.168.1.130/php/login.php?mobile=" + login_user.text.toString() +
                    "&password=" + login_password.text.toString()
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To do this in Android 9 Pie you will have to set a networkSecurityConfig in your Manifest application tag like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
     <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
     </application>
</manifest>
```

Then create a xml file named network_security_config just like the way you have named it in the Manifest and the content of your file should be like thisto enable all requests without encryptions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

> If this is not working, please make your request from a secure domain(HTTPS).

Comment: Thanks, but did you read the description ? I already said that one doesn't help.

Comment: Please make your request from a secure domain(HTTPS).

Comment: I have checked your answer again, and it's working perfect, so I will make it as accepted one.

Answer (score 9):

Add this into your Manifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

like this..

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
...
 </application>
```

Comment: Attribute usesCleartextTraffic is only used in API level 23 and higher

Comment: @zeleven Please check this out [https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942262/7212498]

Comment: I have checked it, but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. Please, check the accepted answer above.

Comment: error: attribute android:usesCleartextTraffic not found.

Comment: @Androidcoder   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" is there you have to add this line in Manifest file

Comment: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:8000.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue recently with android 9 pie.

I added in my Manifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
```

second line is mentioned is to ignore the warning for SDK less than 23.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really appreciate it. This worked for me as well.

Comment: I found the  tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" helpful for suppressing warning in android sdk version less than 23