# How to fix 'Cleartext HTTP traffic to x not permitted' in xamarin android

Tags: http, xamarin.forms, https, xamarin.android, cleartext

I have an issue in my application Cleartext HTTP traffic to x not permitted.

I've already tried putting android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in my manifest. But i want to change "android:usesCleartextTraffic" flag to "false" to prevent unencrypted traffic  from being sent.

How to solve this?

Comment: Do you want to disable `usesCleartextTraffic` programmatically ?

Comment: I am getting Cleartext HTTP traffic to x not permitted issue. How to solve this issue without enabling the android:usesCleartextTraffic as true in manifest file

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54827498/8187800.

Comment: How did you solve this, please @SoftDev ?

Answer (score 43):

If at some point you want to move to *MAUI* (which has no `AssemblyInfo.cs`), you might want to add `UsesCleartextTraffic`) to your Application attribute in `Platforms/Android/MainApplication.cs`:

```
#if DEBUG                                   // connect to local service on the
[Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]  // emulator's host for debugging,
#else                                       // access via http://10.0.2.2
[Application]                               
#endif
public class MainApplication : MauiApplication
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 20):

You can fix this with one line of code.
Open AssemblyInfo.cs in your android project under properties and add the code below:

```
[assembly: Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]
```

Comment: I might also recommend wrapping that in `#if DEBUG` and `#endif`, in case you want to only allow this behavior in debug builds.

Answer (score 20):

In Maui, expand Platforms/Android and edit MainApplication.cs.

Replace "[Application]", near the top, with "[Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]"

Comment: thanks I was specifically looking for this

Comment: Basically a duplicate of my answer, but for release versions of serious apps, you definitely want to restrict network connections to only use TLS. It may lower the review rating if you upload an app to GooglePlay that still allows http connections. Therefore I recommend the ``#if DEBUG``.

Comment: You are my hero! Saved time. Was looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are accessing a server that doesn't support HTTPS, then you can create exceptions in your network security config.
You can create a file `net_sec_conf.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<network-security-config>
  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
    <trust-anchors>
      <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
  </base-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">api.example.org</domain>
    <trust-anchors>
      <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and then in manifest file add this line:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/net_sec_conf"
```

(assuming you have put the file in xml folder).
This way cleartext HTTP traffic will only be allowed for the specified domain.

Of course, if the server supports HTTPS, then you just need to change your URL "http://..." to "https://...".

Comment: I tried something like this, but could not found out how to make the net_sec_conf.xml to be added in the artifact. In side the apk file there was a res/xml folder, but it did not contain the added file net_sec_conf.xml. Solution from @Mordecai with the debug-comment from Mike worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for .Net MAUI.

What worked for me:

1. Create a file named network_security_config.xml in Platforms\Android\Resources\xml (create the 'xml' folder if does not exist).
2. Add this configuration to the file, replace YOUR_IP_ADRESS with your machine ip adress, which you can get by running 'ipconfig' in cmd and copy the value of 'Adresse IPv4':

   ```
    <network-security-config>
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">YOUR_IP_ADRESS</domain>
        </domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
   ```
3. Go to AndroidManifest.xml right click -> open with -> XML Editor(depends on the IDE you are using) and add the following values to the application node:
   <application .... android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" ...>
4. Go to MainApplication.cs in the Platforms/Android folder and add the following code as an attribute to the class:

   ...
   #if DEBUG
   [Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]  // for development,
   #else
   [Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = false)] // production
   #endif
   public class MainApplication : MauiApplication
   ...

Happy coding!