# Maui Net7 Android HttpClient thrust self signed certificate not work

Tags: http, ssl, https, maui, webdav

Im working on the port from Xamarin (Android) to Maui Net7 (Android).

I have a HTTPClient for Webdav Calls.
Under Xamarin i use the ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback but under Maui Net7 this callback is never called!

```
httpHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => {                 return true;};'
```

In the first step i get the error that Propfind Http method not supported, i use the
`<UseNativeHttpHandler>false</UseNativeHttpHandler>` in the project to fix this.

After i test the SSL, i get an SSL error and the callback ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback is not called under Maui Net7 (Android).

**I need to support self signed certificates, how can I do that under Net7 Maui (Android)?**

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Use the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553277/allowing-untrusted-ssl-certificates-with-httpclient#18232008
Do you need to trust all certificates or just self signed ones? Or only from a specific domain? Also, it seems like using WebRequestHandler would be better from this post. I cannot verify that all of these work on android, but they probably do.

Comment: Never mind, from the documentation it says “ Provides desktop-specific features not available to Windows Store apps or other environments.”

Comment: The documentation on MSDN seems a little lacking in terms of version support. MAUI doesn’t show up like Xamarin or Net Standard. It is difficult for me to find an alternative right now, I would recommend using a separate library.

Comment: You can refer to this case which is about [trusting additional CAs and make use of the Android certificate store in a net6 MAUI solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72276421/trust-additional-cas-and-make-use-of-the-android-certificate-store-in-a-net6-mau).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72276421/trust-additional-cas-and-make-use-of-the-android-certificate-store-in-a-net6-mau
now it works when I add the CA certificate in Android,then the callback ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback is also executed.

However, the certificate must be installed in Android!

WebRequestHandler can not be used in Android.

Is there also a way to trust all server certificates?

Comment: It seems there is no a such way. The android has the limit about trusting certificates.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i work 2 weeks on this problem under Maui, on Xamarin works all perfect. I hope the maui team fix all the issues soon. Thank you Liyun Zhang!

Comment: You can post an new issue on the github.