# ERROR: "Trust anchor for certification path not found" - .NET MAUI

Tags: android, certificate, maui, android-network-security-config

There are some possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72276421/trust-additional-cas-and-make-use-of-the-android-certificate-store-in-a-net6-mau).

But I received an error: "resource xml/network_security_config (aka com.companyname.test:xml/network_security_config) not found"

Where do I need to create a config XML file to have access to the Android manifest file?

I just want to linked xml file to the android:networkSecurityConfig in Android manifest.

Comment: Can you show the construct of it and did you set its build action as AndroidResource?

Comment: I'm resolved my issue with 'ngrok' but thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test .NET MAUI app on localhost API and avoid issue for SSL cert, you can use a tool https://ngrok.com/

"ngrok" will put localhost on the internet - it's working for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).