# Kotlin HTTP GET data & insert into textView

Tags: kotlin, http, url, get, textview

> Hey developers, I'm having a problem with finding a way in Kotlin for Android to GET HTTP data and insert it into a textView.

```
   val HTTPget = findViewById<View>(R.id.buttonPOst) as Button
    HTTPget.setOnClickListener{

        val t = findViewById<View>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName) as EditText
        val result = URL(t.toString()).readText()


        // Device 1
        val net1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewzx)
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val adid = result.toString()
            Log.e("MainActivity","ADID="+adid)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                net1.setText(adid)
            }
        }
```

> I thought that URL(t.toString()).readText() was the right way, but it is giving me this error code:

```
[PatchStore] create disable file for com.thordalenterprise.httpgetter uid is 10179
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.thordalenterprise.httpgetter, PID: 8301
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1565)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
atcom.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.jav
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.jav
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionIm
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:248)
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1072)
at kotlin.io.TextStreamsKt.readBytes(ReadWrite.kt:150)
        at com.thordalenterprise.httpgetter.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-1(MainActivity.kt:60)
        at com.thordalenterprise.httpgetter.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$yqRXLCuKxvg6aIX1POsLtCj1iGk(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.thordalenterprise.httpgetter.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7192)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7166)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:824)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27592)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:888)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8301 SIG: 9
```

> > I should use the okhttp library? But I would like a very simple way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing to get text from person name field try below code

```
 val HTTPget = findViewById<View>(R.id.buttonPOst) as Button
HTTPget.setOnClickListener{

    val t = findViewById<View>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName) as EditText
    val result = URL(t.text.toString()).readText() //here change


    // Device 1
    val net1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textViewzx)
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val adid = result.toString()
        Log.e("MainActivity","ADID="+adid)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            net1.setText(adid)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I still get

E/rise.httpgette: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to info.cern.ch not permitted
 at com.android.okhttp.HttpHandler$CleartextURLFilter.checkURLPermitted(HttpHandler.java:115)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:458)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
 at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:244)

Comment: @AnxiousDino ok so existing error resolved and now another new error getting now add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" this line in application tag of manifest file for more check https://stackoverflow.com/a/55605275/6834114

Comment: Thanks, but not helping. I have updated the Error Message above according to the error message I get when I run it. :)