# What's the usage of tools:targetApi="m"?

Tags: android, namespaces, attributes, android-manifest, manifest

I have an app uses `clearText` between Android-client and server using `Retrofit`, and in `Android 9+` it's not allowed to use `clearText`.

To ignore that I added         `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `Manifest` but it warns:         `tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"` and suggests to add `tools:targetApi="m"`.

It's a bit confusing:

- Is the `tools:targetApi="m"` means that any attributes with `tools:` is for Marshmallow and higher?
- Is it for using this version of Manifest or something else? Is this making unwanted mistake in my app?

My Manifest:

```
...
<application
    android:name=".ApplicationClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
    tools:targetApi="m">
    ...
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/TargetApi) you can read:

> Indicates that Lint should treat this type as targeting a given API level, no matter what the project target is

This means it will affect **only** the annotated one.

Other attributes with `tools` won't be affected. `tools` is a namespace, from which you can get attributes, an attribute won't affect the entire namespace.

Comment: I updated my question. see my main tag... how `tools:targetApi` can detect which attribute must affected in api m?

Comment: The `tools:targetApi` only affects `Lint`

Comment: So it basically just removes the annoying red wavy underline. That's it.

Comment: If I use it in Styles.xml, tools:targetApi="p" and use that style in OS below "P" will it crash the app ? or it will ignore the line attribute for below "P" ?

Comment: @Pankaj just declare a new styles.xml file which targets that API and use what you need there. Don't try to mess up with the framework.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti Yes, but according to documentation, it is completely safe to use it in default styles.xml, because system will ignore it on lower versions

Answer (score 20):

By adding `tools:targetApi="m"` to an element you tell the [lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint) that the element won't be used on API level below 23 (M). See the [attribute documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#toolstargetapi).

> This tells the tools that you believe this element (and any children) will be used only on the specified API level or higher. This stops lint from warning you if that element or its attributes are not available on the API level you specify as your minSdkVersion.

In this particular case `<application>` uses `android:usesCleartextTraffic` attribute which is available starting from API 23 but the app `minSdkVersion` is less then 23 so lint warns you. Despite specifying `tools:targetApi` removes the warning in this case it isn't a right solution because the `<application>` can be used on older API levels if `minSdkVersion` allows it. But such a trick won't harm because `android:usesCleartextTraffic` will be ignored if it isn't supported, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50942262/4858777) for more details.

What about `tools` namespace in general, it contains attributes which used by build *tools* and won't affect runtime behavior. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes) for more details.

> Android Studio supports a variety of XML attributes in the tools namespace that enable design-time features (such as which layout to show in a fragment) or compile-time behaviors (such as which shrinking mode to apply to your XML resources). When you build your app, the build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK size or runtime behavior.

Comment: So should we add `tools:targetApi="m"` when specifying clear text in Manifest of a project that has min SDK of 21 or not?