# React Native release apk does not fetch data from local network

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk, mobile-development

I created a react-native app, it is working fine.

If I generate a debug APK and install it on the devices, it works fine and fetches data from the local database as it should.

However, if generate `gradlew assembleRelease` the APK's are generated successfully, but when I install it on the devices it does not fetch data from the same network which it fetches from the same network if generate a debug APK.

[Here](https://github.com/sh4rif/react-native-restaurant-app) is the URL of the repo https://github.com/sh4rif/react-native-restaurant-app.

Comment: Do you have the right device permissions to access network?

Comment: ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />``` add in manifest.xml  above <application> tag.

Comment: I suggest connecting your device to your pc via usb and run `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V` to see the log, then test the feature and see if the url is correct or if there is any error.

Comment: @lava it is already there

Comment: @karlmarxlopez this is the very first app I created using react-native followed a few tutorials from the internet. If had the experience of creating the apps using react-native I am sure I would have fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, iOS will block any request that's not encrypted using SSL. If you need to fetch from a cleartext URL (one that begins with http) you will first need to add an App Transport Security exception. If you know ahead of time what domains you will need access to, it is more secure to add exceptions only for those domains; if the domains are not known until runtime you can disable ATS completely. Note however that from January 2017, Apple's App Store review will require reasonable justification for disabling ATS. See Apple's documentation for more information.

On Android, as of API Level 28, clear text traffic is also blocked by default. This behaviour can be overridden by setting android:usesCleartextTraffic in the app manifest file.

[Please refer to documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network)

Comment: Thank you @Anurag Chutani I have a local network it's a local app that runs on android devices to take orders from restaurants. Data lives inside the restaurant premises, therefore, running on a local server running xampp.

Answer (score 3):

@Anurag's answer explains the issues in detail because I had a similar experience when I was developing my app I got help from this [@article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/04/protecting-against-unintentional.html) and from this StackOverflow [@post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555256/how-to-use-androidusescleartexttraffic-below-marshmallow-api-23).

The simple solution is to add the following lines to the `AndroidManifest.xml` under the `<application` tag.

```
<application
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

This error comes because in Android, when we try no `SSL` certificate API call, Android blocks it, that's why it happens.

```
<application
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

this will work perfect.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer. If you have any unique approach to solving this issue,  Please edit the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

add
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> with <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" >` in the manifest file(android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml) .
worked with http
(flask server), android 9